# Abort / Stop SignalR connection from server with a message and status code

Tags: asp.net-core, server, signalr

I'm creating a SignalR server and I added a couple of rules that the clients should follow when they want to connect to server.

The rules (also call them 'validators') are, for example, that a certain header should be present when the client request to connect.

My question is: how can "reject" a connection with a proper "status code" and "message" and kick out the user?
I didn't find any helpful thread around.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I Checked  the hub class and found:

[image]
and if the connection is assciated with httprequest,you could use Context.GetHttpContext() method to get the httpcontext,
So I tried as below:

```
public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            var errormessage = "the connection was disconnected due to Some reason";
            var header = Context.GetHttpContext().Request.Headers;
            if (header.ContainsKey("Origin"))
            {
                await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("Disconnect", errormessage);
                Context.Abort();
                .......                
            }
            
        }
```

The Result：
[image]
[image]